# Integrating Java with Z3

Tags: java, z3, smt

I would like to ask ,  How to Integrate Java with SMT Z3 solver ?
It would be great if there will be described not only theoretical questions, but also some implementation experience.

Comment: Basically you ask people to do the research and work for you.

Comment: There is plenty of information about those subjects on the internet. You can do research, try out some things and if you encounter specific problems you can ask a question. Like this question for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883107/equality-for-constants-in-z3-smt-solver

Comment: you mean ,, it's doable ?  thank you very much indeed for a help

Comment: probably but what im saying is that you should do some research and try some things out.

Comment: okay, if there are any problems , I will drop it here

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what kind of integration you are looking for, but I thought I should mention that we are currently working on a Java API for Z3. This can be previewed in the unstable branch of Z3, obtained at [Z3 Latest Source Code](http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/BrowseLatest). This is not distributed in any binary packages yet, so you would have to build the source code yourself. It basically comes as a jar package (+DLL) and the source code comes with an example of how to use it in examples/java.

Comment: I have a set of array-lists < >. I want to write a constraint using Z3 to retrieve a data from these array-lists